# Undefined behaviour of scanf() in a do-while loop

Tags: c, input, character, scanf, do-while

I'm currently learning C by a book "C Programming a modern approach" and encountered this code. When I tried to run it, after typing consecutive characters like 'abc' and hitting Enter (new line), nothing was printed. Please explain what is going on here.

```
char ch;
do {
    scanf("%c" , &ch);
} while (ch != '\n');
printf("%c", ch);
```

Comment: What was the code actually supposed to do?

Comment: you are overwriting the char, so only '\n' will be printed

Comment: Move `printf("%c", ch);` inside the loop. You are printing one charatcer - newline.

Comment: note that if the book told you to read one char with scanf rather than getchar, you should discard the book.

Comment: Regarding your title: "Undefined Behavior" (UB) is a term usually used for something else (your code does not have UB). See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should generally provide a [mre] of the problem, which includes a function `main` and all `#include` directives. This allows other people to easily test your program, by simply using copy&paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're asking the user to input a character using `scanf`. This is happening in a loop *until* the user inputs a `'\n'` or newline character (the same as pressing the enter key), which is when the loop will break.

Your print statement will then print the character in the variable `ch`, which at that point will be `'\n'` (since this variable just stores one character, the last one you typed).

This newline character will probably be invisible when you run your program so you may not be seeing it. You can add another print statement after the loop and if that print statement starts at a newline, you know that the `'\n'` was printed on the previous line.

Something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char ch;
    do 
    {
        scanf("%c" , &ch);
    } while (ch != '\n');
    
    printf("%c", ch);
    printf("I should show up on a newline");
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @ AbdurRehmanKhan: you should also mention that `scanf()` would return `EOF` at end of file, causing `ch` to remain unchanged, causing either undefined behavior when comparing `ch != '\n'` or an infinite loop is the input stream has at least one byte but no newline. This approach to reading input is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

> When I tried to run it, after typing consecutive characters like `abc` and hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> (new line), nothing was printed.

Well with the posted code, if the loop even finishes, the last byte read by `scanf("%c", &ch)` and stored into `ch` is the newline character. Hence `printf("%c", ch)` outputs this newline and it seems *nothing* is printed but something is, the newline which is invisible on the terminal but does move the cursor to the next line.

You can make this more explicit by changing the `printf` call to this:

```
    printf("last value: '%c'\n", ch);
```

Note however that the posted code is not a recommended way to read the contents of the input stream:

- `scanf("%c", &ch)` may fail to read a byte if the stream is at end of file. Failure to test this condition leads to undefined behavior (`ch` is unmodified, hence stays uninitialized if the input stream is an empty file) or to an infinite loop as `ch` may never receive a newline.
- this code is a typical example of a `do` / `while` with a classic bug. It would be much better to write the code using `getchar()` and a `while` loop.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int c;         // must use int to distinguish EOF from all valid byte values
    int count = 0; // to tell whether a byte was read at all
    char ch = 0;   // the last byte read

    // read all bytes from the input stream until end of file or a newline
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n') {
        ch = (char)c;
        count++;
    }
    if (count == 0) {
        printf("no characters entered: ");
        if (c == EOF) {
            printf("end of file or read error\n");
        } else {
            printf("empty line\n");
        }
    } else {
        printf("last character on line is '%c'\n", ch);
        if (c == EOF) {
            printf("end of file or input error encountered\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```